# I can't printf() or write() my array after using a read() on stdin to check for '\n' (enter)

Tags: arrays, c, printf, stdio

I am writing a small program that is supposed to print out sin(counter), while counter is incremented by 0.01 every time I put in '\n' (Enter) in the console.

Both `printf("%lf", sin_output[0]);` and `write(1, &sin_output, sizeof(sin_output));`do **not** print **anything** to the console.
Through debugging I found out that the rest of my code is working as intended, right before sin_output[0] is printed, it is filled with the correct value of sin(counter).

I chose an array, because I want the program to write into a socket or pipe later on, for which a printf() is useless to my knowledge.

I tried reproducing this error in a small program that goes as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  double array[1];
  array[0] = 1;
  printf("%lf", array[0]);

  return 0;
}
```

This prints out the correct value.
Output: 1.000000

Substituting `printf("%lf", array[0]);` with `write(1, array, sizeof(array));` gives out some random characters, which is due to write() formatting my output to a string maybe?

Using `write(1, &array, sizeof(array));` prints the same gibberish.

Now I tried `array[0] = sin(x);`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  double array[1];
  double x = 0.01
  array[0] = sin(x);
  printf("%lf", array[0]);

  return 0;
}
```

Which prints 0.010000 for some reason (rounding?).

Using `double x = 0.1` prints out the right value.

So I tried every option I know of in a minimal reproducible system. All of the programs output at least something, be it a wrong or unwanted value.

Using the (almost) exact same structure, of `array[1] = sin(enter_counter)` in my code however prints no value whatsoever. None.

I suspect it to be thanks to me using `read(0, &buf, sizeof(buf))` and the program producing some unwanted behavior with the stdin/stdout buffer, which leads to stdout not printing properly both for `printf` and `write()`.

My code for the actual program is:

```
/* includes*/
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* main function*/
int main() {
  /* declare variables*/
  char buf[1];
  double enter_counter = 0;
  double sin_output[1];

  /* reset buf*/
  memset(&buf, 0, 1);

  /* master loop*/
  while (1) {
    /* read stdin*/
    read(0, &buf, sizeof(buf));

    /* if stdin == enter key, progress sin by 0.01rad*/
    if (buf[0] == 10) {
      enter_counter += 0.01;
    }

    /* reset buffer*/
    memset(&buf, 0, 1);

    /* calculate sin for enter_counter*/
    sin_output[0] = sin(enter_counter);
    
    /* printf sin(enter_value)*/
    printf("%lf", sin_output[0]); 
    //write(1, sin_output, sizeof(sin_output));
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `read` and `write` only deals with the raw binary data. There's no text-conversion.

Comment: Comment out the read and hard-code a value into buf.. Does that change anything?

Comment: @nicomp Commenting out the read() and using `buf[0] = '\n'` prints something and it looks like a sin.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Does that mean, that the write() should print out the expected value, or that there is no way to actual write() the right value into the console? If I want to send the data trough a pipe or socket, is there a way to parse it "back to normal" after receiving it and printing out the right thing from the receiver?

Comment: Add a newline in the call to `printf()`, or call `fflush()` after it.

Comment: Take the value of `array[0]` in your first example. Usually a `double` value is eight bytes (64 bits), and none of the bytes will contain anything close to the string `"1.0"` or similar. If you write the raw binary data, you will write the raw value of those eight bytes. Probably none of them will correspond to nice printable ASCII characters.

Comment: "_I chose an array, because I want the program to write into a socket or pipe later on_" Please clarify... Your program can send binary data (like a `double` using `write()`) or a formatted string (like `"3.14159"` using `fprintf()`) down a pipe... What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Lets take a different example, the `int` value `1`. Assuming the common 32-bit `int` that will either be stored as the four bytes `0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01` or `0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00` in memory. If you write that to a terminal expecting ASCII (or UTF-8) encoded characters, then that will be written as either the special character `NUL` (`0x00`) or `SOH` (`0x01`). Neither of those characters are printable, and on Windows it's usually printed as some symbols.

Comment: For any kind of IPC, even locally, I recommend using a text-based format. So you first need to come up with a nice format (or pick an existing one, like JSON) and then *serialize* the data you have into the text-format to send it. There are many libraries to do such serialization (and deserialization on the other end) for you. I don't recommend you do it yourself, unless you create a very specific and *simple* protocol.

Comment: @Fe2O3 In the end I want to convert the value of sin(counter) into cJSON, send it over a pipe into a program that formats the cJSON into a printable format, prints it out and sends the values over yet another pipe into a program that can plot the values (probably GNUPLOT).

Comment: Once you have the message you want to send, as a null-terminated string, you can use `write` to write the string itself, and `read` on the other end. But remember to include the string null-terminator, and also remember that on the receiving end you might need multiple calls to `read` to read all of the message (and you might also get parts of the next message).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a newline to your print statement as such:

```
printf("%lf\n", sin_output[0]);
```

This yields the following for me:

```
$ ./a.out 

0.010000

0.019999

0.029996

0.039989

0.049979

0.059964
^C
```

Not sure exactly what's going on, but likely that your output is being buffered, and then overwritten by your own newline. Look into output buffering to get a better understanding.

Comment: This solved it, thanks. It is most likely how you explained it. I'll look into output buffering. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @Fe2O3 Fid that, I wanted to declare the post as solved but couldn't find it. Thanks for all the help!